# Properly terminate a QThread

Tags: c++, qt, qthread

I've have a worker class that do image acquisition in the background.

```
void acq::run ()
{
    while (m_started)
    {
        blocking_call();
    }
    emit workFinished();
}

void acq::start ()
{
    m_started = true;
    run();
}

void acq::stop ()
{
    m_started = false;
}
```

`start ()`; `stop ()` are slots and `workFinished` is a signal.

So in my UI Class, I launch the worker and I connect the signals to the slots :

```
m_thread = new QThread;
m_worker = new acq();

m_worker->moveToThread(m_thread);

// When the thread starts, then start the acquisition.
connect(m_thread, SIGNAL (started ()), m_worker, SLOT (start ()));

// When the worker has finished, then close the thread
connect(m_worker, SIGNAL(workFinished()), m_thread, SLOT(quit()));

m_thread->start();
```

At this point, I implemented the slot, `closeEvent`

```
void UIClass::closeEvent (QCloseEvent *event)
{
    m_worker->stop(); // tell the worker to close
    m_thread->wait(); // wait until the m_thread.quit() function is called
    event->accept(); // quit the window
}
```

Unfortanely, `m_thread->wait()` is blocking. Even if the signal `quit()` is emmited

Thanks

edit:

I added these two connections :

```
connect(m_worker, SIGNAL(workFinished()), m_worker, SLOT(deleteLater()));
connect(m_thread, SIGNAL(finished()), m_thread, SLOT(deleteLater()));
```

and a Qdebug into `acq::~acq()`

The message is printed that prove, that stop is called, workFinished is emitted, deleteLater() is emitted.

Comment: Have you used your debugger to ensure that the thread you're waiting for has actually terminated - and if it's not terminated, what it's doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of Ralph Tandetzky and Kevin Krammer I finally found a solution.

- Instead of closing the thread with  `m_worker->stop();`, I use `QMetaObject::invokeMethod(m_worker, "stop", Qt::ConnectionType::QueuedConnection);` and `QCoreApplication::processEvents();` in the worker event loop. The behavior does not change, but I hope it will prevent race condition or other problems.
- Instead of using : `connect(m_worker, SIGNAL(workFinished()), m_thread, SLOT(quit()));`, I use a custom slot :

  ```
  connect(m_worker, &Acq::workFinished, [=]
  {
      std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(100));
      QMetaObject::invokeMethod(m_thread, "quit", Qt::ConnectionType::DirectConnection);
  });
  ```

  We use DirectConnection because we are outside the infinite loop, so the event are not processed.
- With that, I had a last problem. `m_thread->wait` is blocking, and I've to read events, otherwise, my custom slot will never be called. So added an event loop to my UI Class `QEventLoop m_loop`.
  Just before `m_thread->wait()`, I wrote `m_loop.exec();`
  And finally, In my custom slot, I put `m_loop.quit()`

  ```
  connect(m_worker, &Acq::workFinished, [=]
  {
      std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(100));
      QMetaObject::invokeMethod(m_thread, "quit", Qt::ConnectionType::DirectConnection);
      m_loop.quit();
  });
  ```

  `m_loop.exec()` process event until quit `m_loop.quit()` is called. With that method, I don't even need `m_thread->wait()` because `m_loop.quit()` is called when `workFinished` is emitted. I don't need    `QMetaObject::invokeMethod(m_thread, "quit", Qt::ConnectionType::DirectConnection);` anymore

Now it works like a charm

EDIT: This solution is very heavy and ugly, Qt (https://www.qtdeveloperdays.com/sites/default/files/David%20Johnson%20qthreads.pdf) sugest to use subclass and requestInteruption in my case.

Answer (score 3):

A normal signal/slot connection between objects on different threads requires that the thread of the receiver object runs an event loop.

Your receiver thread does theoretically run its event loop, but the event loop is busy executing the `start()` slot because `run()` never returns.

You either need to unblock the receiver event loop or call the stop slot with a `Qt::DirectConnection`.

When doing the latter you need to be aware that the slot is now called in the context of the sender thread and you need to protect `m_started` against concurrent access.

Alternatively to using your own flag you could use `QThread::requestInterruption()` and `QThread::isInterruptionRequested()`

Comment: Thanks for responding. I've few questions :  
  - A normal signal/slot connection between objects on different threads requires that the thread of the receiver object runs an event loop. Receiver is the woker right ? - but the event loop is busy executing the start() slot because run() never returns. Why the qDebug in the stop() function is called if the worker is busy ? Do you have any example ?

Comment: @Epitouille , is `stop()` slot getting called in your case?

Comment: @Mike yes it is

Comment: @Epitouille , does that happen after you've added `QCoreApplication::processEvents()` to your while loop?

Comment: No, it happends from the beginning

Comment: @Epitouille in your case the stop() funtion is called directly, so it actually doesn't require an event loop.
However, you also need to quit the thread's event loop, e.g. `m_thread->quit()` after `m_worker->stop()'

Comment: Hmm, you are calling `quit()` via a signal slot connection, so that should be enough. You definitely need to protect `m_started` e.g. with a `QMutex` though.

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
QCoreApplication::processEvents();
```

to your loop and it'll work.

The reason you deadlock is that the call to `acq::run()` blocks and does not leave time for `acq::stop()` to be executed on the worker thread.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I don't think QCoreApplication::processEvents(QEventLoop::WaitForMoreEvents); is the solution. Adding this line in the acq::run() loop is blocking my thread. The worker is stuck in this line. However, acq::stop() is called because my qDebug() in this function (slot) appears.

Comment: @Epitouille Did you also `QObject::invoke` the `acq::stop()` slot?

Comment: Yes I changed m_worker->stop() to QMetaObject::invokeMethod(m_worker, "stop", Qt::ConnectionType::DirectConnection);

Comment: It should be a `Qt::ConnectionType::QueuedConnection` instead, so the worker thread actually executes it. This avoids a data race on `m_started` and this undefined behavior. Also I just edited my answer: I removed the `QEventLoop::WaitForMoreEvents` argument from `processEvents()`. Hope it works now.